# How to filter pyspark dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, filter, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have seen many questions related to filtering pyspark dataframes but despite my best efforts I haven't been able to get any of the non-SQL solutions to work.

```
+----------+-------------+-------+--------------------+--------------+---+
|purch_date|  purch_class|tot_amt|       serv-provider|purch_location| id|
+----------+-------------+-------+--------------------+--------------+---+
|03/11/2017|Uncategorized| -17.53|             HOVER  |              |  0|
|02/11/2017|    Groceries| -70.05|1774 MAC'S CONVEN...|     BRAMPTON |  1|
|31/10/2017|Gasoline/Fuel|    -20|              ESSO  |              |  2|
|31/10/2017|       Travel|     -9|TORONTO PARKING A...|      TORONTO |  3|
|30/10/2017|    Groceries|  -1.84|         LONGO'S # 2|              |  4|
```

This did not work:

```
df1 = spark.read.csv("/some/path/to/file", sep=',')\
            .filter((col('purch_location')=='BRAMPTON')
```

And this did not work

```
df1 = spark.read.csv("/some/path/to/file", sep=',')\
            .filter(purch_location == 'BRAMPTON')
```

This (SQL expression) works but takes a VERY long time, I imagine there's a faster non-SQL approach

```
df1 = spark.read.csv("/some/path/to/file", sep=',')\
            .filter(purch_location == 'BRAMPTON')
```

**UPDATE** I should mention I am able to use methods like (which run faster than the SQL expression):

```
df1 = spark.read.csv("/some/path/to/file", sep=',')
df2 = df1.filter(df1.purch_location == "BRAMPTON")
```

But want to understand why the "pipe" `/` connection syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using the backslash, you can do:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = spark.read.csv('/some/path/to/file', sep=',') \
     .filter(col('purch_location') == 'BRAMPTON')
```

Your first attempt failed because the brackets are not balanced.

Also it seems there are some spaces after the string `BRAMPTON`, so you might want to `trim` the column first:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, trim

df = spark.read.csv('/some/path/to/file', sep=',') \
     .filter(trim(col('purch_location')) == 'BRAMPTON')
```

Comment: I got the following error: `NameError: name 'col' is not defined`

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian you need to import it, see my edited answer?

Comment: yeah, my bad, i guess i hadnt run the previous cell

Answer (score 2):

you can use `df["purch_location"]`

```py
df = spark.read.csv("/some/path/to/file", sep=',')
df = df.filter(df["purch_location"] == "BRAMPTON")
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to use the `/` connector, I should have mentioned I was able to do it outside the connection